# android studio mapping.txt show annotation

Tags: android

After I build my apk with andrid studio,the mapping.txt show some lines with "#" like below.I wonder how these annotations come into being?

Is it a new android studio feature? But I don't want it.

Comment: the annotation like this: # {"id":"sourceFile","fileName":"MediaBrowserCompat.java"}

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.